# User likes on django accumulation

Tags: django

I have a simple pinterest clone app built and have a basic activity stream setup.
The activity stream only records when a new image is created, when an image is liked, when a new user is created, or when a followed user follows another user.

What I would like to implement and do not know how is accumulation, for example if 2 or more user like a certain image, I would prefer the activity stream to say:

"User 1 and User 2 like image"

Can any one help me achieve this?

Comment: I would recommend setting up a `Like` model and having a `ForeignKey` back to your Image and User models to track the set of "likers". From that you can get the count, individual users, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Action models in [django-activity-stream](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/blob/master/actstream/models.py#L47) could be helpful.

For example, when an Actor performs an action, you could look up if there was recently a similar Verb and Target combination by a different Actor, and then replace that earlier instance with a new one that includes the most recent Actor.